# Have a column copy index value on insert?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table like so

```
index, name, secretindex
```

I can define secretindex as a timestamp or a static value on mysql(phpmyadmin,cpanel) but how can I set it so whenever I insert a row, it will automatically assign its self to the primary index id (unique)? the secretindex will always change but it starts off as the primary index.

Basically code wise, I'm accessing tables with the secretindex and if the secretindex is -1 (not set), it defaults to the index. If I can just have it automatically set to the index I'll save a query function.

Comment: I tried, but I realy don't get what you mean by "but how can I set it so whenever I insert a row, it will automatically assign its self to the primary index id (unique)?" Can you elaborate?

Comment: you can use a trigger for that. On Insert it would copy the id, on Update it would leave it as it is.

Comment: index id is unique, secretindex needs to copy that after insert. Jeff basically got what I wanted haha, just don't know how to setup the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger for that task.

Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_id 
  AFTER INSERT ON `tableName`
     FOR EACH ROW SET @id = NEW.index
       BEGIN  
          UPDATE `tableName` (secretIndex)
          VALUES (@id)
          WHERE index=@id;
       END;
```

THIS IS NOT TESTES and just Dummy-Code, as I don't have too much information...